# How to only return an array from this class?

Tags: php, curl

I'm a preocedural programmer, and dont know much about objects.

I have the following class (found it on SO)

```
class MultiCurl
{
    private $allToDo;
    private $multiHandle;
    private $maxConcurrent = 20;
    private $currentIndex  = 0;
    private $info          = array();
    private $options       = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                                   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                                   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 1,
                                   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 3);

    public function __construct($todo, $concurrent)
    {
        $this->allToDo = $todo;
        $this->maxConcurrent = $concurrent;
        $this->multiHandle = curl_multi_init();
    }

    public function process()
    {
        $running = 0;
        do {
            $this->_addHandles(min(array($this->maxConcurrent - $running, $this->_moreToDo())));
            while ($exec = curl_multi_exec($this->multiHandle, $running) === -1) {
            }
            curl_multi_select($this->multiHandle);
            while ($multiInfo = curl_multi_info_read($this->multiHandle, $msgs)) {
                $this->_showData($multiInfo);
                curl_multi_remove_handle($this->multiHandle, $multiInfo['handle']);
                curl_close($multiInfo['handle']);
            }
        } while ($running || $this->_moreTodo());
        return $this;
    }    

    private function _addHandles($num)
    {
        while ($num-- > 0) {
            $handle = curl_init($this->allToDo[$this->currentIndex]);
            curl_setopt_array($handle, $this->options);
            curl_multi_add_handle($this->multiHandle, $handle);
            $this->info[$handle]['url'] = $this->allToDo[$this->currentIndex];
            $this->currentIndex++;
        }
    }        

    private function _moreToDo()
    {
        return count($this->allToDo) - $this->currentIndex;
    }

    private function _showData($multiInfo)
    {
       // $this->info[$multiInfo['handle']]['multi'] = $multiInfo;
        $this->info[$multiInfo['handle']]['curl']  = curl_getinfo($multiInfo['handle']);
        $this->info[$multiInfo['handle']]['content']  = curl_multi_getcontent($multiInfo['handle']);
        return $this->info[$multiInfo['handle']]; 
    }
}
```

When I actually use it:

```
$concurrent = 20;
$mc = new MultiCurl($nodes, $concurrent);
$output = $mc->process();
print_r($output);
```

I simply want it to output the multi-dimentional array of all the responses, so only what the "_showData" function returns.

Currently it returns a bunch of other stuff like:

```
[allToDo:MultiCurl:private] => Array
[multiHandle:MultiCurl:private] => Resource id #11
[maxConcurrent:MultiCurl:private] => 20
[currentIndex:MultiCurl:private] => 100
[info:MultiCurl:private] => Array
```

I only need the contents of "[info:MultiCurl:private]" array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the process method, instead of

```
return $this;
```

use

```
return $this->info;
```

Comment: This seems to work, however the array starts at 12. Its not really a big deal.. just interesting why.

Answer (score 2):

add public method to class "MultiCurl". for example:

```
public function getInfo() {
  return $this->info;
}
```

if you don't wanna edit the class file, extend and use it.

```
Class MultiCurlWrapper extends MultiCurl {
    public function getInfo() {
      return $this->info;
    }
}
```

Comment: And after, do I just use $output = $mc->getInfo(); ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Would `print_r($output[info:MultiCurl:private]);` work?</strike>

And if the keys of the `$output` array are always the same, could you access it with

```
print_r($output[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method to get what you need as the current function returns the object.

In its simplest form;

```
public function getInfo()
{
  return $this->info;
}
```